# Replace the comma between two selected words using regex replacement

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace the comma (,) between two selected words. here is the input

`test normal content [ABC]new, ball, test[/ABC]`

output
`test normal content [ABC]new[/ABC][ABC] ball[/ABC][ABC] test[/ABC]`

I actually want to add prefix and suffix. currently, I using

```
(?i)\[ABC\](.+?), (.+?)\[/ABC\]
<div class="$1">$1</a> <div class="$2">$2</a>
```

but in this way, i have to add a rule for each number of words. so i thought if i can replace the comma with `[/ABC][ABC]` and then I can simply use regular replace with [/ABC] and [ABC] to add prefixes and suffixes. it's a little bit complicated for me to write regex replace for such a problem. any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\[ABC]|\G)[^[,]+\K,(?=.*\[/ABC])`
- Replace with: `[/ABC][ABC]`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
    \[ABC]      # literally [ABC]
  |           # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
)           # end group
[^[,]+      # 1 or more any character that is not square bracket or comma
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
,           # a comma
(?=         # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    .*          # 0 or more any character
    \[/ABC]     # literally [/ABC]
)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]